# Implementing real-time signal processing filters

Tags: signal-analysis, real-time

I’m currently working on my capstone for school, and I’m looking for some guidance/tips when it comes to real-time filtering. The nature of the project is to monitor breathing patterns, send the aquired signals wirelessly, and then process/filter the data using a mobile app. My part of the project is the latter, and I would like some tips in terms of coding language/various articles that could guide me in the right direction! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a recent (2015) 150+ pages review called [Smartphone-Based Real-Time Digital Signal Processing](https://doi.org/10.2200/S00666ED1V01Y201508SPR013) with [lab codes](http://sites.fastspring.com/bookcodes/product/bookcodes). There are chapters like:

- 2: Android Software Development
- 3: iOS Software Development
- 6: Real-Time Filtering
- 7: Adaptive Filtering

> Real-time or applied digital signal processing courses are offered as
>   follow-ups to conventional or theory-oriented digital signal
>   processing courses in many engineering programs for the purpose of
>   teaching students the technical know-how for putting signal processing
>   algorithms or theory into practical use. These courses normally
>   involve access to a teaching laboratory that is equipped with hardware
>   boards, in particular DSP boards, together with their supporting
>   software. A number of textbooks have been written discussing how to
>   achieve real-time implementation on these hardware boards. This book
>   discusses how smartphones can be used as hardware boards for real-time
>   implementation of signal processing algorithms as an alternative to
>   the hardware boards that are currently being used in signal processing
>   teaching laboratories. The fact that mobile devices, in particular
>   smartphones, have now become powerful processing platforms has led to
>   the development of this book, thus enabling students to use their own
>   smartphones to run signal processing algorithms in real-time
>   considering that these days nearly all students possess smartphones.
>   Changing the hardware platforms that are currently used in applied or
>   real-time signal processing courses to smartphones creates a truly
>   mobile laboratory experience or environment for students. In addition,
>   it relieves the cost burden associated with using a dedicated signal
>   processing board noting that the software development tools for
>   smartphones are free of charge and are well-developed. This book is
>   written in such a way that it can be used as a textbook for applied or
>   real time digital signal processing courses offered at many
>   universities. Ten lab experiments that are commonly encountered in
>   such courses are covered in the book. This book is written primarily
>   for those who are already familiar with signal processing concepts and
>   are interested in their real-time and practical aspects. Similar to
>   existing real-time courses, knowledge of C programming is assumed.
>   This book can also be used as a self-study guide for those who wish to
>   become familiar with signal processing app development on either
>   Android or iPhone smartphones.